# How to rollup .js file with code having export default () {}?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, rollup, rollupjs, quasar-framework

I've one .js file having the below code in it.

```
export default (vueInst, obj, events) => {
  for (const eventName of events) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Error

> Error     at Function.missingTransform in
> /node_modules/buble/dist/buble.cjs.js:376:9

This file exists in my quasar app extension with UI kit. But when I run yarn build it gives error because there is no plugin to rollup this .js file with the above code.

Which plugin should I use to rollup such files?

Below is my current rollupPlugins:

```
const rollupPlugins = [
  nodeResolve({
    extensions: ['.js'],
    preferBuiltins: false
  }),
  json(),
  VuePlugin(),
  buble({
    objectAssign: 'Object.assign'
  })
]
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: `Error
    at Function.missingTransform in /node_modules/buble/dist/buble.cjs.js:376:9`

Comment: It looks like there is nothing wrong with your code which is normal esmodule code? Can you post your full code in a repo to have a look?

Comment: Actually I haven't launched repository. But that js file is having that much code only. More simple 2--3 lines inside. Code is correct but i think I need rollup plugin which can roll that .js file

Comment: The error is likely from `buble` plugin, try to comment out other plugins to see if there are any collision among them?

Comment: You mean I should remove `bubble` and try?

Comment: Yeah can try that way too :)

Comment: Wow it worked !

Comment: Can you also share full your configuration? I don't think `bubble` is a problem since it's like babel

Comment: Which configuration? Actually I'm using quasar app extension with ui kit. Its more line config https://github.com/mesqueeb/quasar-ui-easy-forms/blob/master/ui/build/script.javascript.js

Answer (score 0):

For me the actual cause of the error was further down in the output. I was able to workout that buble was unable to transform a section of my code (a for loop). I rewrote it and the error went away.

Example of what I changed from

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    console.log(key, value);
}
```

and to

```
Object.entries(obj).forEach(
    ([key, value]) => console.log(key, value)
);
```

Comment: Is there any reason why is this happening? Got this same exact issue and was able to fix it using Object.entries